# Mysql8.0 event 'committing alter table to storage engine' hangs During DDL after high traffic load

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-8.0

Is anyone here familiar with the wait event "committing alter table to storage engine".

All i can find about it is "The server has finished an in-place ALTER TABLE and is committing the result."

The Issue I have is that when I run 'alter table drop partition' or 'alter table reorganize partition' (daily process to maintain retention) the event takes **significantly longer after committing many transactions** (rate of 600 inserts p/s) on the table for a couple of hours.

during this event all sessions are locked on "Waiting for table metada lock" and the app is down.

If i run the "alter table drop/reorganize partition" command shortly after another such command it completes in ms as if there is some cache i need to free to reduce the event.

I tried flush table ... with read lock - did not help (thought it might be related to dirty pages)

I am using mysql version 8.0.27 on RDS

We did not have this issue in 5.7 (I am familiar with the ddl lock changes in mysql8) but it seems that there is something i am missing here since this happens only after massive rate inserts for a couple of hours and does not hang otherwise.

**Some more details:**

1.Create table big_table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` text,
  `c4` text,
  `c5` text,
  `c6` text,
  `c7` text,
  `c8` text,
  `c9` text,
  `created_day` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`created_day`),
  KEY `c1_index` (`c1`,`created_day`),
  KEY `c2_index` (`c2`,`created_day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=124732836 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(created_day)
(PARTITION p20220906 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-06') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220907 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-07') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220908 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-08') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220909 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-09') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220910 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-10') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220911 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-11') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220912 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-12') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220913 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-13') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220914 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-14') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220915 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-15') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220916 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-09-16') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

2. Insert many records into the table (i ran for 10 hours python script with 200 threads , inserting about 10M total of records)
3. stop the above Inserts , DB is now idle , nothing running on it:
4. Drop a partition with the following command , note drop takes 18 seconds even though partition is empty:

> ```
> mysql> alter table big_table drop partition p20220904; 
>     Query OK, 0 rows affected (18.16 sec) Records: 0 Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

5.During the drop i ran mysql engine info(cant attach the entire file here but I noticed something interesting , note how many reads and writes and fsyncs are done) :

```
MySQL thread id 5427, OS thread handle 23425529054976, query id 198927824 192.168.200.5 root committing alter table to storage engine
alter table big_table drop partition p20220904
...
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 55
1008709 OS file reads, 73662575 OS file writes, 1109352 OS fsyncs
0.55 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 9.18 writes/s, 3.18 fsyncs/s
```

4. Drop another partition with the following command , This time it takes less then a second :

> ```
> mysql> alter table big_table drop partition p20220905; 
>     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec) Records: 0 Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

5. Conclusion : There is some background process introduced (or changed) in mysql8 (maybe buf_flush_or_remove_pages() ) when running a DDL such as drop or exchange partition which is doing some sort of flush of all committed data or checking the flush_list , locking the table for reads and writes and setting a checkpoint(?) state for the table.

6.Question : How do we overcome this hang time

Comment: Sounds like you should report this so the devs an have a  look

Comment: Where are many flavors of `ALTER`.  Please provide the `ALTER` in question, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Also, how big is the table?  And provide `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` if you can catch it while it is hung.

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.
All that is required is changing a dynamic parameter :

```
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0
```

Once we changed it,  the alter partition command which used to take up to 5 minutes takes now 0 seconds.